# using aggregate in generic view django rest

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am going to calculate sum of a field in django but I am failing to do this I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'model'
```

with `annotate` it works but it shows one field multiple times that's why I need to use aggregate

here my code

```
class TestStatistics(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    filter_class = TestStatisticsFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        test_id = self.request.GET.get('test_id')

        data =  Test.objects.filter( test_id=test_id).aggregate(total=Sum('total'))
        print(data)
        return data
```

can anybody help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever get_queryset() is called you should return a queryset but not a result.
aggregate returns a result whereas annotation returns queryset, hence annotation worked.

If one field shows multiple times, look at your data and refine your queryset accordingly, switching to just aggregate doesn't help in this case.